Swiftui MSLA Logout catche issue

 func loadMSALScreen() async throws -> MSALReturnTokenUserID {
        
        //MSALGlobalConfig.loggerConfig.logLevel = .verbose
        
        do {
            let authority = try MSALB2CAuthority(url: URL(string: MSALConfig.msalAuthorityURL)!)
            let pcaConfig = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: MSALConfig.msalClientID, redirectUri: MSALConfig.msalRedirectURL, authority: authority)
            pcaConfig.knownAuthorities = [authority]
            let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: pcaConfig)
            let webViewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: self)
            let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: [MSALConfig.scopes], webviewParameters: webViewParameters)
            interactiveParameters.promptType = .login // Ensure B2C UI/UX requires username & password login
          //  interactiveParameters.promptType = .selectAccount
            let result = try await application.acquireToken(with: interactiveParameters)
            
            // Failure on fallthrough No Token
            if result.accessToken.isEmpty && result.idToken == nil {
                return .failure(CommonError.noLoginAccessToken)
                
            }
    }
}


public class func logout() -> (Bool,String) {

        do {

            let authority = try MSALB2CAuthority(url: URL(string: MSALConfig.msalAuthorityURL)!)
            let pcaConfig = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: MSALConfig.msalClientID, redirectUri: MSALConfig.msalRedirectURL, authority: authority)
            pcaConfig.knownAuthorities = [authority]

            let application = try MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: pcaConfig)
            
            if KeyChainServices.shared.accountIdentifier == "" {
                return (false, "" )
            }
            
            let account = try application.account(forIdentifier: KeyChainServices.shared.accountIdentifier ?? "")

             try application.remove(account)
           
             return (true,"success")
            
        } catch  {
            print("Received error signing out: \(error)")
            return (false, "" )
        }
        
    }
}

try application.remove(account)

I'm using this code for  login logout  using MSAL when login it starts webview ...is getting logout successfully. But when I login again its not asking username and password .directly moving into dashboard screen.
Note :Need to remove login cookies.

I don’t see any SwiftUI here
